# git could not read from remote repository, trying to push branch

Tags: git

I'm trying to do `git push origin my_branch` but I'm seeing the below error:

```
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address 'blah blah' to the list of known hosts.
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

This is what I've tried already:

```
ls -al ~/.ssh
    
drwx------  5 krisp staff   160 Aug 24 12:19 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 67 krisp  staff  2144 Sep 13 08:07 ..
-rw-------   1 krisp  staff   419 Aug 24 12:15 id_ed25519
-rw-r--r--   1 krisp  staff   110 Aug 24 12:15 id_ed25519.pub
-rw-r--r--   1 krisp staff  3167 Sep 13 08:05 known_hosts
```

then

```
ssh -T git@github.com
Hi kri9ep! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

I saw this somewhere so I tried this:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
/Users/KrisP/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory
```

and when I try this:

```
eval $(ssh-agent -s) 
Agent pid 5123
```

Someone mentioned to change the url in the .gitconfig file but I don't have url, this is what my .gitconfig file looks like:

```
[user]
    email = my_email@etc.com
    name = Kristoph P
[credential]
    helper = osxkeychain
```

Answer (score 0):

`ERROR: Repository not found.` You're connecting fine. The repository does not exist. Check that you have the right path to the repository.

Run `git remote -v` and look at the URL. For example.

```
$ git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:user/repo.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:user/repo.git (push)
```

Check `git@github.com:user/repo.git` is correct for your repository. If not, use `git remote set-url <new-url>` to change it.

> Someone mentioned to change the url in the .gitconfig file but I don't have url, this is what my .gitconfig file looks like:

They meant the config file in your local repository. `.git/config`. You'll see something like this.

```
[remote "origin"]
        url = git@github.com:user/repo.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

You can edit that, but a mistake can leave your repository broken. It's probably best to leave that alone. Use [`git-remote`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote) to manipulate it.

Comment: thanks for responding! it looks correct when I do git remote -v   I see the same format that you showed in your example. Instead of changing the .gitconfig file and adding the url, what would you suggest as a fix?

Comment: @kris360media I'd double check by copying the ssh URL from GitHub and pasting it into `git remote set-url` just to be sure there's no typos. If that doesn't work, is this a private pubic or private repository?